# Using Google-Sheet's SUMPRODUCT with a conditional

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to calculate a `sumproduct` given a condition.

In this example a `sumproduct` of `A` and `B` where date is `1/1`

I tried trowing `if` in here, but result makes no sense.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(if(C5:C7=G5,D5:D,E5:E))
```

Please help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

`=SUMPRODUCT(C5:C10=G5,D5:D10,E5:E10)` works. Quite elegantly, I might add.